# Include font from resource folder

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

I am trying to have a label in my WPF-Window that has a special font that is probably not installed on all computers.

This is currently my xaml-code for the label:

```
<Label x:Name="ping" Content="00" FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/resources/#visitor" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="165,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

And here is my project hierarchy:

[image: project]

But why doesn't the font appear in the application/on the label?

Comment: What's the Build Action for the font file (File properties -> Build Action)? If it says anything other than "Resource", try changing it.

Comment: Alright, so I changed it from "None" to "Resource", but it still doesn't work. Maybe something with the Uri isn't correct?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to drag up an old thread, but I found the solution to this. While the font filename is visitor1, FontFamily doesn't look for this and instead looks for the font name. Open the font file and you'll see the name is actually "Visitor TT1 BRK". Use this in your code and it will work:

```
FontFamily="CustomFonts\#Visitor TT1 BRK"
```